# How to get char from binary in haskell?

Tags: haskell, binary, char

Given an 8-bit binary, I want to get its char representation. For example:

[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1] which, I belive, is the binary representation of 'a'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem consists of two pieces. 1) Convert a list of binary digits into an `Int`. 2) Converting an `Int` to a `Char`. Hoogle [tells us](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20Char) that we can use [`chr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Char.html#v:chr) for that.

Answer (score 5):

```
import Data.Char

ord2chr :: [Int] -> Char
ord2chr = chr . foldl (\a b -> 2*a + b) 0
```

Now you can try

```
> ord2chr  [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1]
'a'
```

Answer (score 4):

As I suggested in my comment, the question can be split in two. Here's a suggestion for the first part, where I've for Haskellness' sake declared a `Bit` type:

```
data Bit = Zero | One

fromBits :: (Integral a) => [Bit] -> a
fromBits bits = foldl f 0 (zip [0..] (reverse bits))
    where
      f x (_, Zero) = x
      f x (n, One) = x + 2^n
```

So what does this do? Well, your question suggests that your bit list has the most significant bit first. We'll process it in reverse, so we do `reverse bits`. Then, we need to keep track of the powers of two the various elements in `reverse bits` represent, which is what `zip`ing with `[0..]` does, producing [(0, least-significant-bit), (1, second-least-significant bit), ...]. Finally `foldl` consumes this list of pairs, with the helper function `f` adding the appropriate powers of 2 to the accumulator.

I've used the `Integral` typeclass to not have to choose an integral type. You can use `Int`, or even `Word8`, in your 8-bit case. For longer bit lists, one could use `Integer` for arbitrary precision (see also (*) below).

For the second part, we can use [`chr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Char.html#v%3achr) to convert an `Int` to `Char`, and if we know that our bit lists aren't too big(*), `fromIntegral` can convert our `Integral` type `a` to an `Int`.

So, what you want can be written as:

```
convert :: [Bit] -> Char
convert = chr . fromIntegral . fromBits
```

In your case, `convert [Zero, One, One, Zero, Zero, Zero, Zero, One]` is `'a'`.

(*) Of course, if they were, the conversion wouldn't make obvious sense anyway. But here's a point I'd like to bring home: We've split the problem in two pieces, and it turns out that the first part (processing the bit list) can be solved in a way that could be useful in a more general setting. For example, `fromBits (One:(replicate 100 Zero))` is 2^100.